# Kubuntu mounting network drives not allowing full access

Tags: kubuntu

I have been trying to mount 3 different network drives hosted from 3 different devices and each one has the same issue it mounts I can get in but Kubuntu sets it as root privileges by default so I cant move anything around add or delete files or folders, if I path directly to them in the networks aria in Dolphine I have access, However I cant move large amounts of files without issues using the GUI I almost always have issues  eather the file dosent finish moving it gets stuck at 99% then fails or after a few min or sec the move just fails, that is why I am trying to mount I have tried the standard mounting in the default location I have tried mounting in my user account aria both give me the same results. Other distros make it easy that are based on debian such as mint but I have put so much into my setup with Kubuntu I don't want to move.

Comment: Can you provide more technical details? For example, the exact steps you are taking to mount these volumes. Also provide details about them. How are they being served? What actions are you taking to move files and what errors are you getting exactly? When you say "it fails" what is the exact behavior of your device? It's hard to decipher what you mean when you use a narrative that doesn't actually describe your exact actions or the device's exact behavior. FYI Mint is based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian. Kubuntu **is** Ubuntu, it just uses KDE as the DE

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show us the `mount` results for the "network" drives, in addition to your `/etc/fstab` entries. Which network drives?

Comment: found out affter going though multiple forms that I needed to add uid=useraccount wich solved most of my issues, hopefully now ill be able to move things around without disconnect issues.